# claviska/jquery-selectBox how to display default value?

Tags: jquery

I a using claviska jquery select box
https://github.com/claviska/jquery-selectBox

following is the code

```
<div class="section">
    <label>Location</label>
    <div>
        <select class="small selectBox" id="GeoLocation"style="display: none; padding: 6px;">
            <option value="1">London</option>
            <option value="2">Madrid</option>
            <option value="3">Paris</option>
            <option value="4">New York</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no problem when the list is static, it is displayed the list box appropriately.
My question is, how can i set the default value in the select box using information i'm getting from server side.

By default i am getting 'London' as a default value.

support i have in JS 
`var id=2` (which is Madrid), how can i set the selectBox to display 'Madrid' as the default value?

how do i build the list in JQuery?

Following the HTML that is being generated be default (London is selected)

```
<div>
    <select class="small selectBox" id="GeoLocation" style="display: none; padding: 6px;">
        <option value="1">London</option>
        <option value="2">Madrid</option>
        <option value="3">Paris</option>
        <option value="4">New York</option>
    </select>
    <a class="selectBox small selectBox-dropdown" style="width: 62px; display: inline-block;" title="" tabindex="0">
        <span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 35px;">London</span>
        <span class="selectBox-arrow"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
var id=2;
// Select the option with the corresponding value..
// capture the text or html inside it

var city = $('#GeoLocation option[value="'+ id+ '"]').text();​

// Set the text to the text in select    
$('.selectBox-label').text(city);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/74Vf2/1/)**

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve .. Do you want to populate the selectBox-label span with the selected item

Comment: In the generated example, you can see the 'London' is written in 'selectBox-label'. i want to replace it to 'Madrid' according to 'val id=2'. thanks